# TypeError: You provided 'false' where a stream was expected occurs while using booelan for checking condition in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

global-error-handler.ts:42 TypeError: You provided 'false' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable.

My code is given below:

```
getPreloadPendingCountSuccess$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(fromActions.GetPreloadPendingCountSuccess),
      switchMap(({ count, shouldUpdateMovements }) => {
        return shouldUpdateMovements && count > 0 && [fromActions.GetPreloadPendingMovementsRequest()];
      })
    )
  );
```

If I remove shouldUpdateMovements  boolean it works fine but it is require. How can I fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should return an array, if you do && , and the first condition is false, it will return false instead

```
        return shouldUpdateMovements && count > 0 ? [fromActions.GetPreloadPendingMovementsRequest()] : [];
```